# Pandas: Combining multiple dataframes/csv files horizontally while they all share the same column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I have a number of pandas dataframes comprised each of two columns, one column named 'dates' with a list of dates and one named 'result'. I wish to be able to combine all of these dataframes into 1 dataframe, with a single 'dates' column and multiple 'result' columns, one for each dataframe I have added. I am trying to display the results as a line graph in streamlit.

This is how I sort of imagined it looking:

df1

| date | result |
| --- | --- |
| 01/06/2023 | 0.5 |
| 02/06/2023 | 2.4 |
| 04/06/2023 | 6.5 |

df2

| date | result |
| --- | --- |
| 01/06/2023 | 0.7 |
| 03/06/2023 | 0.5 |
| 04/06/2023 | 0.2 |

df1 + df2

| date | result | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/06/2023 | 0.5 | 0.7 |
| 02/06/2023 | 2.4 |  |
| 03/06/2023 |  | 0.5 |
| 04/06/2023 | 6.5 | 0.2 |

I have already tried `concat` with `axis = 1` however it seems that what is holding me back is that all the csv files have the same key for the columns, which causes an error.

Does anyone know a way to make this work, or a workaround of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using concat, use "merge" from pandas. It will merge all the dataframes in one final dataframe.

For example:

```
final_df = dataframes[0]

for df in dataframes[1:]:
    final_df = pd.merge(final_df, df, on='dates', how='outer')

print(final_df)
```

Comment: Re *"In spite of"*: Don't you mean *"Instead of"*?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with the `index_col` parameter for setting the first column to an index:

```
import glob

dfs = [pd.read_csv(file, index_col=0) for file in glob.glob('path')]

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

If the input is a list of DataFrames with two columns:

```
df = pd.concat([x.set_index(x.columns[0]) for x in dfs], axis=1)
```